# Create New Modern Landing Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I'm working on creating a new page that I want to be my new landing page. The landing page and the new modern page are a bit different. Mainly, pages have your name at the top and the title of the page. If I remove all of that, it still keeps a white space at the top. Is there anyway I can remove that? Or set the page template to be a landing page that you get when you build a new site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is how to create a new page using the `Home` layout, not how to set it as the new home page.

The easiest way is to go into the Site Pages library and create a copy your existing page, this will set the right layout.

Another way would be to create it using PowerShell:

```
Add-PnPClientSidePage -LayoutType Home -Name "New home!"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! PNP to the rescue again. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set your new page as home page in modern SharePoint online site, follow the below steps :

Go to the “Site Pages” library -> select “**select your new page .aspx**” ->click on “**Make homepage**”

Details steps here:

[In 2 steps convert a classic SharePoint page to modern using PnP](https://www.google.com/amp/s/global-sharepoint.com/powershell/in-2-steps-convert-a-classic-sharepoint-page-to-modern-using-pnp/amp/)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to site settings -> Welcome Page under Look and Feel -> Set your Welcome Page
2. Go to site content -> Site Pages -> select the new page -> Right click -> Click “Make homepage”.
3. Go to SharePoint Designer, set home page in the ribbon.